# MySQL 8: Install component_validate_password in my.cnf get error

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8 server. I want to install component_validate_password.so component from my.cnf definition rather than execute SQL statement "INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';". Therefore I can define the password policy options in the my.cnf.

So I add lines in my.cnf:
`[mysqld] plugin_load_add = component_validate_password.soe`

But I got errors when startup the server:
2021-02-09T01:33:23.473579Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010900] [Server] Can't find symbol '*mysql_plugin_interface_version*' in library.
2021-02-09T01:33:23.474015Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010736] [Server] Couldn't load plugin named 'component_validate_password.so' with soname 'component_validate_password.so'.

Please advise.

Comment: Please check component_validate_password.so file exists in plugin directory or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think the package name is validate_password only